# Firebase dependency in Android Library: Cannot invoke method get() on null object

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm experiencing a build issue when adding a firebase dependency to a android library.

My setup is as follows

**/settings.gradle**

```
include ':module-lib'
include ':module-app'
```

**/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
  } 
}
```

**/module-lib/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
   ...
}
dependencies{
  api "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"  
}
```

**/module-app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   ...
}
dependencies {
  implementation project(':module-lib') 
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Short log:**

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :module-app
Detected alwaysUpdateBuildId set to false while obfuscation is enabled. This may result in obfuscated stack traces in Crashlytics.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :module-lib:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> Cannot invoke method get() on null object
> Cannot invoke method get() on null object

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
13 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 5 from cache
```

You can find the full stacktrace of the original error in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TG3XUWc5)

The **funny thing** is that `module-lib` only contains a placeholder, empty and useless class. If I removed the firebase dependency from `module-lib` and move it to `module-app`, the build works fine.

I'm not using Android Studio, so this is a purely Gradle and/or plugin 
 and/or dependencies issue.

Also note that

```
./gradlew clean       // Always succeds 
./gradlew build       // Sometimes works with above error 
./gradlew clean build // Always fails with above error
```

This also happens with any `firebase-*` dependency included in a module that applies the library plugin `com.android.library`.

More environment info

```
$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64
```

Any clues or tips are more than welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a way around this?

Comment: No. Not yet. It looks like a race condition, as from the command line sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. It always fails in Android Studio though.

Comment: @NamiAlejandroSalimi check the answer. Updating the plugin to 4.0.1 solved the issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Upgrading the `google-services` plugin to version `4.0.1` fixed the issue.

From the Firebase sdk changelog page: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

[image]

In other words, change this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

to this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: I'm seeing this error with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: Downgrade to 4.0.1 and give it a try. There might be a regression bug.

Comment: Same issue with 4.1.0 as @SimpleJ Downgrade fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me after changing the version

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.0
```