# Cannot invoke method containsKey() on null object

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I got this error when I was building my Android project by gradle.   It roughly happened once per week.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':xxxxxxxx:compileDebugAidl' property 'importDirs' during up-to-date check.
> Cannot invoke method containsKey() on null object

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Any idea what may cause this error? thanks

Comment: Can you please `Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace`

Comment: what's your gradle plugin version ?

Comment: Or better: `--scan` in somewhere at gradle.properties

Comment: I am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'    I can't replicate it propertly. It's only happened randomly.

Comment: @Cody, I'm seeing the same problem randomly. Is there any chance you have the  'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin applied as well?

Comment: @AndroidEx  yes. we have this in our codebase.

Comment: Just got it today again. It's clearly related to the gms plugin but that's all I have for now...

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114705291 - related issue in google tracker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @tapchicoma comment to the original question, the issue: [NullPointerException in Google Services Plugin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114705291) now is marked as fixed for `4.2.0`.

So, the final solution is to update to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Until the bug is fixed by google, downgrading to the play services 4.0.1 seems to have fixed this issue for me so far:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930048/4096987

Comment: This issue is related to issuetracker.google.com/issues/114705291  as pointed by @tapchicoma .
The workaround suggested is to downgrade to 3.x.x .

Comment: @alexfdz That is just one opinion. Like I mentioned, we've experienced this issue first-hand on my team and downgrading to 4.0.1 has been enough to resolve it in our case.